# iOS App's file associations ("open with..") / CFBundleDocumentTypes question

Tags: ios, ipad

I have recently bought a perfect file manager app for my iPad. Everything in this app is great, besides that it cannot handle some specific file types.

So for example if I try to download the file in mobile safari and try to save it into the file manager (for further upload to dropbox, email and so on), I cannot do this because the app is not listed in the "open In" list.

The question is, how to associate this app with this specific file types? I've searched google and found out that app's file association information is stored in Info.plist file in the CFBundleDocumentTypes section.

So I just modified Info.plist but id didn't help. I also found the cracked version of this app and placed info.plist into the IPA file, reinstalled the app on the iPad and it also didn't help.

Any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just add the file types. The app also has to be coded to accept the request to open the file.

Try contacting the developer and ask for them to add this feature.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is probably not the APP but a limitation on IOS: it is a random selection and only shows 10.  I don't know if it randomly selects based on the ones you use most or what. You cannot change this other than to delete apps you don't use as often.  But having said this, the app must also support the extension of the document you are trying to send: not just as a document it stores, but as a document it accepts as a transfer from another app.  You can try to convert it first into a PDF and then open, if that's possible.  Hope this helps.